# Index & in Sphinx?

Tags: exception, sphinx

I keep adding to my `exceptions.txt` file in m `Sphinx` configuration for acornyms that contain `&` e.g:

`A&E => A&E`

so that it is not indexed as two separate letters.  However it is getting monotonous and I wonder if I can/should somehow just make '&' indexed. The questions are:

1. How do I force `&` to index
2. Will `A&E` then index as such?
3. Is there a downside I'm not 'getting' since Sphinx decides to not index & in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add `&` to charset_table 
   http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-charset-table.html
2. should do
3. There is a small chance of things like 'marks&spensors' means that would only ever match that exact form (ie wouldnt match say marks & spensors as different.

Might want to consider
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-blend-chars.html
instead, so get somewhat best of both.

Comment: Oh! Blended Characters are PERFECT. Among other things I don't have to add an entire character set and it also mirrors some more manual work I had to do with & and - etc. Thank you sir!